# Re-wrote git history with bfg but not reflected in earlier commits

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

A huge folder in my repository has filled up my LFS. As instructed [here](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), I wish to remove the folder from the remote repository and then re-write history to drop it from all previous commits. That should free up lots of space in my LFS, but is not. What am I missing?

Say the repository is `repo` and the folder in question is `repo/unwantedFolder`.

I did the following steps:

1. Removed the unwantedFolder and re-committed:

   ```
   $ git rm -r --cached unwantedFolder/
   $ git commit -a -m 'Drops folder'
   $ git push origin
   ```
2. Mirror-cloned the repo:

   ```
   $ git clone --mirror https://github.com/emagar/repo.git
   ```
3. Re-wrote history:

   ```
   $ java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders unwantedFolder repo.git/
   ```
4. Moved into the manipulated cloned repo: `$ cd repo.git/`
5. Used the git gc command:

   ```
   $ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
   ```
6. Pushed the clean repository: `$ git push origin`
7. Moved back to the original repository: `$ cd repo/`
8. Pulled from github: `$ git pull origin master`

While all seemed to work well, when I inspect old commits in github, the unwantedFolder/ still appears there!

What am I missing?

Comment: I have not actually used git-lfs but logically the large files stored *outside* Git need some sort of outside "discard old large files" stimulator. The problem here is similar to that of submodules: the *repository* has only a reference to (hash ID for) the content; the content is stored separately; the content server has no idea when, or if-ever-at-all, someone will come along and say "give me the content for hash $H".

Comment: Is the [lfs] tag appropriate here?

Comment: I presume the [lfs] tag is appropriate---it is files that are stored in the remote lfs that I wish to expunge from the repository's history. If this is wrong, I can remove the tag...

Comment: How did you inspect old commits, and which branch are they from?  This question could use a publicly-reproducible example repo - the one above has been deleted or redacted.